# Using variables for CSS id in a loop with Jade Pug

Tags: html, css, node.js, pug

I would like to build a loop of collapsable divs in jade / pug.

I am using jade npm package version 1.11.0

For example here is my first iteration which is working:

```
button.btn.btn-primary(type='button', data-toggle='collapse', data-target='#response0', aria-expanded='false', aria-controls='collapseExample')
  | Show Response
#response0.collapse
  .well
    pre=response
```

Unfortunately when I try this one

```
button.btn.btn-primary(type='button', data-toggle='collapse', data-target='#response0', aria-expanded='false', aria-controls='collapseExample')
  | Show Response
div(id= 'response0').collapse
  .well
    pre=session_detail.response
```

Or this

```
button.btn.btn-primary(type='button', data-toggle='collapse', data-target='#response0', aria-expanded='false', aria-controls='collapseExample')
  | Show Response
.collapse(id= 'response0')
#response0.collapse
  .well
    pre=session_detail.response
```

The html output looks great but the collapse button doesnt work.

What I would like to build is something like this that works:

```
-var i = 0
-session_details.forEach(function(session) {
  .row
    .col-md-5
      pre=session_detail.response
      -var dataTarget='#response'+i
      -var dataTargetResponse='response'+i
      button.btn.btn-primary(type='button', data-toggle='collapse', data-target=#{dataTarget}, aria-expanded='false', aria-controls='collapseExample')
        | Show Response
      div(id= dataTargetResponse).collapse
        .well
          pre=session_
  -i++
```

Do you have any ideas of what could I do? 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an array when using a for loop in pug. Or you can use while, something like this;

```
- var i = 0;
.row
  .col-md-5
    while i < 4
      .collapse(id='response' + i)
      i++
```

More information over at the [pugjs iteration](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html) page

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`each` loop of Pug](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html) to loop over an array and deal with each item in that array.

If you need to generate content in such a loop with different id's in each loop, you can use the `index` of the array in the loop, like in the following example:

```
- var sessions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
each session,index in sessions
  button.btn.btn-primary(type='button', data-toggle='collapse', data-target= "#response"+index, aria-expanded='false', aria-controls='collapseExample')
    | Show Response
  .collapse(id= "response"+index)
    .well
      pre=response
```